# Change windows hostname from command line

Tags: windows, hostname

This question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989/change-windows-hostname-from-command-line, but I'm in a different situation. The netdom tool will not work on a computer not joined to a domain. I've tried setting the hostname from the registry, but I was wondering if there was another way from the command-line.

Comment: Have you looked at the other solutions on that page? Assuming that they work all you'd need to do would be to copy the script to notepad, change the hostname in the script, save it as something.vbs and then run it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right from the link you provided:

```
wmic computersystem where name="OLDNAME" call rename name="NEWNAME"
```

Then reboot with

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Comment: How careless of me. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Joe - No prob! If this solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking the check box under the voting to the left of my answer.