# How to rename Win7 machine without a mouse

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Synergy is a picky PITA, but I love it.  I have the "client" machine which only has a keyboard and sometimes I need to rename it so synergy stops complaining.  Is there a way to rename a windows machine with only the keyboard.  For some reason pressing Alt+Enter on Computer just makes an error noise, is this a setting, or new win7 feature?

Comment: Why do you need to rename the windows machine? Why is synergy complaining? There has to be a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change windows hostname from command line](http://superuser.com/questions/150781/change-windows-hostname-from-command-line)

Comment: @MaQleod pursuing those other avenues:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/114324/how-to-kill-synergy-evict-all-connections and http://superuser.com/questions/402534/alttab-for-things-in-the-dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows 7, hit the "Windows key". That should open up the start menu.
In the cmd/run box, type "computer name".
That should give you a couple options, one is rename computer.
In that dialog, tab down to "change"
That's it.