# Alt+tab for things in the System Tray

Tags: windows, dashboard

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works great for flipping between proper applications, but what if I want to see all the little icons by the clock and I don't have a mouse?  Is there an alt+tab equivalent for the system tray icons?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will move focus to the System Tray icons.  You can then use the arrow keys and enter to move between and select them.

For more info you can check "[The Master List of New Windows 7 Shortcuts](http://lifehacker.com/5390086/the-master-list-of-new-windows-7-shortcuts)" over on LifeHacker.com.